# 3D primitive rendering library

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, c, directx9

I am looking for a library which would easily allow me to render shapes (cubes, spheres, lines, circles, etc.) in 3D3 and OpenGL if possible. I want to be able to rapidly design visual debugging tools and I am not proefficient enough in graphics rendering to do it myself (writing the low level stuff that is). The library would have to be for C/C++.

I've already taken a look at the open-source 3d engine, but I feel those are too big for what I really need.

Do any of you know if such library exist? If so, links would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

**OpenGL** and **[freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)** will do what you're looking for.  Freeglut can create the spheres, cubes, cylinder, cone, donuts, teapots, etc.

> GLUT (and hence freeglut) allows the user to create and manage windows containing OpenGL contexts on a wide range of platforms and also read the mouse, keyboard and joystick functions.

[**http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/**](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).

There are differences between them. With FreeGLUT you can control OGL context, window properties, single/double buffering, multi-sampling etc.

SFML is more object-oriented. You can set FPS with it, it offers you multi-threading, image loading, etc. It sets window itself (it always uses RGBA, double-buffering, depth buffer etc.) - you cann't change it, but it's all you need (you don't need to change it in most cases).